# Giving a model knowledge of a many-to-many related model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

EDIT:  Given responses in comments and answer I tried suggestion and I get some errors when trying to query , also doing the related name query does not get the right results (as seen in comments)

BusinessLocations.objects.all()

`Error: QuerySet object has no attribute 'objects' is the error.`

In either case, I did a dump of all the tables and see this:

```
auth_business_permissions', u'auth_permission', u'auth_user', u'auth_user_businesss', u'auth_user_user_permissions', u'django_admin_log', 
u'django_content_type', u'django_migrations', u'django_session', u'ipaswdb_address', u'ipaswdb_billing', u'ipaswdb_billing_businesss', 
u'ipaswdb_designation', u'ipaswdb_business', u'ipaswdb_business_business_locations', u'ipaswdb_businessinsurances', u'ipaswdb_businessinvoices', 
'ipaswdb_businesslocations', u'ipaswdb_businessterm', u'ipaswdb_insurance', u'ipaswdb_insurance_businesss', u'ipaswdb_invoice', u'ipaswdb_employee',
u'ipaswdb_employeeinvoice', u'ipaswdb_employeelocations', u'ipaswdb_employeeterms', u'ipaswdb_specialty']
```

I have a `ipaswdb_business_business_locations` and a `ipaswdb_businesslocations` which seems strange to me, and I wonder if my database is just gunked up?

`Original Question:`

I have two models a `Business` and an Employee.  I want them both to be aware of each other but not directly but through another model called a 'BusinessesLocation`.  I can sort of express this in my models but it doesn't look or feel right.  It is like only the employee knows of the businesses, and not vice vice versa.

I had another question opened to try to answer this but the answer was not 100% correct in that it didn't offer for a many to many it was more like a one to many.  In this case:  An employee can work at many locations (potentially being an employee of many businesses) and a business can have many locations having many employees.

Currently my models work where this shell script works:

`someEmployee.business_locations.all()[0].business.business_name`
and it works fine, I can get all the locations of a business an employee works at and via that infer the many businesses an employee might work for given the businesses locations.

But I cannot figure out how to go the other way, and find out all the employees a business has working for them and at which locations

My current (wrongish) models are like this:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
        business_locations = models.ManyToManyField('BusinessLocations', through='EmployeeLocations')


class EmployeeLocations(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business_location = models.ForeignKey('BusinessLocations', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.provider.first_name

class BusinessLocations(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey('Address', on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    business = models.ForeignKey('Business', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doing_business_as = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.doing_business_as

class Business(models.Model):
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    business_locations = I need something here no idea how
```

Bellow is some pseudo shell code demonstrating how I would like my models to work:

```
#create a new business location assume business has been created
newLocation = Address(...)
business.business_locations.add(newLocation, doing_business_as='alternative name maybe')


#assume employee exists
#add a new business location to the employee
#when i say selected business the form would have current employee then in its locations
#you'd have to select a business first, and get a list of all that businesses locations and you
#you could add the business location and then select another business with all ITS locations
# and add one there too if you wish

employee.employee_locations.add(selectedBusiness.business_locations[0])
employee.employee_locations.add(anotherSelectedBusiness.business_locations[1])

Below is what I cannot figure out how to do, vice versa... 

#now lets see which businesses the employee works for.

for business in employee.business_locations
       business.business_name

#and lets see each businesses employees:
for employee in Employee.objects.all()
       employee.
?? No idea how to build the models to represent these relationships
```

I can get an employees business locations just fine, but I cannot get the above examples of getting a list of employees for a business.  Not sure what I need to adjust (or methods I might need?) to get this to work like I want in my shell example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is Django's concept of [related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects).

> When you define a relationship in a model (i.e., a `ForeignKey`, `OneToOneField`, or `ManyToManyField`), instances of that model will have a convenient API to access the related objects.

You can access the related objects both in queries and as a manager attribute on your models. See the examples in the documentation. In your case this would look something like:

```
# Now lets see which businesses the employee works for:
Business.objects.filter(businesslocations__employee=employee).distinct()

# And let's see each business's employees:
Employee.objects.filter(business_locations__business=business).distinct()
```

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out too that you don't need a `business_locations` field on the `Business` model as a `businesslocations_set` related manager is provided by the `ForeignKey` field on `BusinessLocations` model.

Read up on field lookups too. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups

Comment: This almost works.  The employee objects.filter works 100% correctly.  I can give it a business and get back all the employees.   The `Business.objects.filter` does not work the same, I give it an employee and get back all the businesses the employee does NOT work for.  Also if i take the employee out of all the employee locations I get back [] for that same query. (That does seem right).  So close on this.  Also i did remove the business_locations from the Business model.

Comment: @Codejoy: I'm not sure how you could get that result. You might want to [look at the generated SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) to see if it matches what you expect.

Comment: Ran those, nothing came back looking very suspicious. I am thinking my database is just gunked up.   Running int he shell `>>> BusinessLocations.objects.all()`  gives me an error `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'objects'`  Even though in the `/admin` i can see the table, and the two business locations there are, and one of the locations is the same one the employee has for which the group does not show up in the list from the shell just all the other businesses.

Comment: Good lord I finally figured this out, the problem?  In my shell i was missing the import of BusinessLocations ugh. ty so much for the help!