# Adding a related object as a context value back to a rendered view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a query I can run in a shell and get the right answer given my models and the way the relations work:

```
# And let's see each business's employees:
employees=Employee.objects.filter(business_locations__business=business).distinct()
```

This works great, I can get set that to employees and have all the employees that work for a business.  The trouble is I am not sure a clean way to figure this out when trying to actually use this model and render a list view from it.  If you see the list.html code (last snippet) you can see where I am trying to provide the number of employees working for a business in the list and then ideally provide a link to edit the employees using a [<-- --> arrow widget thingy](http://incrtcl.sourceforge.net/iwidgets/iwidgets/disjointlistbox.gif).

I know I have to do this in the view right below, but I wasn't sure the cleanest way.  Best I could come up with involved a for loop and a map of ids?

I have a view method: in my views.py:

```
def business_list(request):
    object_list = Business.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 25) # 3 posts in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    #make a map into the object list some how so I can have this data at the end...


    try:
        business = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
        business = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
        business = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'ipaswdb/group/list.html', {'page':page, 'business':business, 'object_list':object_list})
```

Then my render view template for that view is this list.html:

```
{% extends "ipaswdb/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Businesses{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <h1>Businesses</h1> <p> Search: </p>

    {% with object_list.count as total_businesses %}
            <h2>
         There are {{ total_businesses }}  businesses
            </h2>
    {% endwith %}
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th> ID</th>
        <th> Business Name</th>
        <th> Comments</th>
        <th> Total employees</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Term</th>

    {% for group in groups %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ business.id }}">{{ business.id }}</a></td>
            <td><a href="{{ business.id }}">{{ business.business_name }}</a></td>
            <td> {{ business.notes|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}</td>
<!-- How do i do this? -->
            <td><a href="linktoaddremoveemployeestoabusiness"> {{ business.business_total }}</a></td> 
            <td> editbutton</td>
            <td>termbutton</td>

        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {% include "pagination.html" with page=groups %}

{% endblock %}
```

Models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
        business_locations = models.ManyToManyField('BusinessLocations', through='EmployeeLocations')


class EmployeeLocations(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business_location = models.ForeignKey('BusinessLocations', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.provider.first_name

class BusinessLocations(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey('Address', on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    business = models.ForeignKey('Business', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doing_business_as = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.doing_business_as

class Business(models.Model):
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I had help with these from this stackoverflow question here:
[Giving a model knowledge of a many-to-many related model in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233245/giving-a-model-knowledge-of-a-many-to-many-related-model-in-django/38234987?noredirect=1#comment63938527_38234987)

Comment: You should show your models.

Comment: Although, having said that, I'm not sure exactly what your question is. You know how to create a link containing the ID of a business, so where exactly are you having trouble?

Comment: Ill post the models but the woe is getting the number of employees per business .  I can do that one at a time using the code i tested in shell (first snippet)  but not sure how to roll that up for the groups collection built in the list view

Comment: Well, I don't see any reference to the number of employees in the code above, but fair enough. Show your models; depending on how their defined, it's probably as simple as `business.employee_set.count`.

Comment: added models you might be right with the employee_set those are the automagic methods created by the Django ORM right?   I forgot about those.... or how to go back and forth.  The models are slightly more complex as their relation is like a through model.  The count I am trying to get is right under the `<!-- How do i do this? -->` I put filler pseudo code which probably looked too much like real code.

Comment: Those models far more complicated than I expected; to be honest I don't really understand them at all. In any case, to get a count of related items for a list you should use [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset); you'll need to work out how to use that to traverse your various relations.

Comment: Yah the models were complex, basically an employee belongs to a business, but via a businesses location.   And so a business has many locations and it can have many employees at each location.  An employee works for a business via the location it works out and it can work for different businesses based on the various locations.   I will look up the annotations.

Comment: Quick question:  Can I build 'helper' methods in my model that might get the information i would commonly want?    For instance I have my little function that gets the employees attached to a business:  employees=Employee.objects.filter(business_locations__business=business).distinct()
 could I put this in my models.py under my class Business and have it return like a list of employees somehow?

Comment: or another question, can I create a field on the fly in the `def group_list` in the `views.py` on the `object_list` array?